# Alignation in Embedded page not same as shown in example for Ext.ux.touch.Grid

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

[The picture comparing the two views I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNHsZ.png)

[image]

The View code is as follows. I am trying to get data for a view on click of a disclosure. Somehow I am not getting the display as grid but one data is coming in one row. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
enabled : true,
paths   : {
    'Ext.ux.touch.grid' : 'js/Ext.ux.touch.grid'
}
});

Ext.require([

'Ext.ux.touch.grid.List',
'Ext.ux.touch.grid.feature.Feature',
'Ext.ux.touch.grid.feature.Sorter'
]);

Ext.define('alarms.view.MyAlarmsDetails', {
extend: 'Ext.ux.touch.grid.List',   
xtype : 'myalarmsdetail',   
 config: {
    fullscreen : true,
    store   : 'TestStore',
    features   : [
            {
                ftype    : 'Ext.ux.touch.grid.feature.Sorter',
                launchFn : 'initialize'
            }
        ],
        columns   : [
            {
                header    : 'Company',
                dataIndex : 'company',
                style     : 'padding-left: 1em;',
                width     : '40%',
                filter    : { type : 'string' }
            },
            {
                header    : 'Price',
                dataIndex : 'price',
                style     : 'text-align: center;',
                width     : '15%',
                filter    : { type : 'numeric' }
            },
            {
                header    : 'Change',
                dataIndex : 'change',
                cls       : 'centered-cell redgreen-cell',
                width     : '15%',
                renderer  : function (value) {
                    var cls = (value > 0) ? 'green' : 'red';

                    return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + value + '</span>';
                }
            },
            {
                header    : '% Change',
                dataIndex : 'pct',
                cls       : 'centered-cell redgreen-cell',
                width     : '15%',
                renderer  : function (value) {
                    var cls = (value > 0) ? 'green' : 'red';

                    return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + value + '</span>';
                }
            },
            {
                header    : 'Last Updated',
                dataIndex : 'updated',
                hidden    : true,
                style     : 'text-align: right; padding-right: 1em;',
                sortable  : false,
                width     : '15%'
            }
        ]
}

});
```

Comment: Well I have also faced the same problem once, long time back. For this you need to make some modifications in the "Ext.ux.touch.grid" folder. You need to debug it properly to solve your issue. Well I am unable to remember the steps that I did, so can't help you properly.

Comment: The problem was solved by adding css corresponding to grid in index.html <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/Ext.ux.grid.List.css" type="text/css">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding css corresponding to grid in index.html